# How to parse JSON that can be either an object or an array?

Tags: android, json

I am getting a JSON string back from my server, which can be either a `JSONArray` or a `JSONObject`, and I do not know beforehand what I'll get (at least not in that part of the code).

Is there a way to handle this? My first guess would be to do something like this:

```
if (jsonString.startsWith("[")) {
   r = new JSONArray(jsonString);
} else {
   r = new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

but this feels a little 'hackish'.

Comment: If possible, talk to the server dev about making the response always an object or always an array

Comment: The server returning two different answers is already a bit hackish. Agree with @TimCastelijns, the cleanest way is changing the server.

Comment: @TimCastelijns luckily, I am the server dev, but I didn't want to touch the interface just yet if there was another solution.

Comment: there are other solutions, such as the one you presented, but none will be as "clean" as making it the server's responsibility to deliver data in a format the client can easily work with

Comment: u can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518252/different-json-array-response

Comment: "at least not in that part of the code" -- isn't this the problem? Shouldn't you be passing some indication, into this part of the code, what is that you are parsing?

Comment: I can't look into your current infrastructure, but I agree with Tim that it is better to change the server. If, for any reason, you have a new client to connect to that same server, you're stuck with this issue again

Comment: @CommonsWare the parser is in a generic part of the code. I should just return a JSONObject back. I will change the server side and the problem just disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `instanceof` with [JSONTokener](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue%20JSONTokener)?

```
Object unknownJSON = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (unknownJSON instanceof JSONObject)
  // well, you know
else if (unknownJSON instanceof JSONArray)
  // you should also know
```

Comment: did you got the result

Comment: I changed the server side, but your solution seems to be the way to do this if that isn't possible.

Comment: @BartFriederichs totally agree that changing the server is the best solution. but its not the answer xD

Answer (score 0):

Very hackish but you can try this

```
try {
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
// u received a json object
} catch (JSONException e) {
// you received a json array
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: I agree that this works, but it is more or less the same as what OP already did with the if statement. Only problem with this would be that if you don't receive JSON for any reason, the catch part will crash

Comment: May be one more catch while parsing as jsonarray. There is no good way to do this on client side.